# Ionic 2 file transfer not adding content length

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload a file with ionic 2 and the cordova-file-transfer. But my server keeps returning an error that content length is missing. How can I add this to my upload headers?

```
 let options: FileUploadOptions = {
            fileKey: 'file',
            fileName: fileName,
            httpMethod: "PUT",
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            chunkedMode: true,
            headers: {
                'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        }
        this.fileTransfer.upload(filePath, submitUri, options, true)
            .then((data) => {
                debugger;
                this.loading.dismiss();
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Upload Success',
                    subTitle: 'Your image has successfully been uploaded.',
                    buttons: ['Dismiss']
                });
                alert.present();
            }, (err) => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                debugger;
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Upload Error',
                    subTitle: 'An error occured while uploading your image. Please try again.',
                    buttons: ['Dismiss']
                });
                alert.present();
            })
```

Comment: Can you add your code please ? Which version of the plugin are you using ? On which platform are you testing (Android, iOS) ?

Comment: Added my code and I using 1.6.2 and testing on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chunkedMode: true,` change to `chunkedMode: false,`

I am working with android, uploaded to azure blob.